# Leptos using NodeRef in an x*y Grid

Tags: html, rust, web-frontend, nodereference, leptos

I have a grid that has `x * y` number of inputs (that also can change over time).
I want to have `NodeRefs` (since I only need to read the values on `submit()` of the form.)
My Idea was a `Vec<Vec<NodeRef<Input>>` making it two dimensional to iterate over like this (columns and rows are `ReadSignal<i32>`).

```
let input_elements: Vec<Vec<NodeRef<Input>>> = (0..rows.get())
        .map(|_| {
            (0..columns.get())
                .map(|_| create_node_ref::<Input>())
                .collect::<Vec<NodeRef<Input>>>()
        })
        .collect();
```

Then using `<For\>` to create those inputs with the refs:

```
  <For
    each=move | (0..rows.get()).into_iter()
    key=|counter| *counter
    children=move |id| {
      view! {
        <Column
          columns=columns.clone()
          input_elements=input_elements.get(id as usize).unwrap().clone()
        />
      }
    }
   />
/>
```

Equivalent using a `Column` component:

```
fn Column(columns: ReadSignal<i32>, input_elements: Vec<NodeRef<Input>>) -> impl IntoView {
    view! {
      <For
        each=move || (0..columns.get()).into_iter()
        key=|counter| *counter
        children=move |id| {
          view! {
            <input
              node_ref=input_elements.get(id)
              type="number"
            />
          }
        }
      />
    }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't build, but doesn't throw me an error either. Which is why I'm currently not really knowing where I'm going wrong/what info I'm missing.

Here's a [codesandbox that doesn't work](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/leptos-playground-forked-3dgv6r?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.rs%3A30%2C16&).

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't throw me an error"*, the codesandbox you link clearly produces a compile time error, **with** several error messages. You should add it to the post if that's your [mre].

Comment: @cafce25 I mean by that, that if you use the current nightly version of rust with the current leptos version and run it in your local environment, then this code will not produce any errors, yet it will not build:
Thats what im getting locally:
warning: `my` (lib) generated 5 warnings (run `cargo fix --lib -p my` to apply 5 suggestions)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 22.09s
       Cargo finished cargo build --package=my --bin=my --no-default-features --features=ssr
       Build failed
No "error could not compile". Codesandbox dosnt take the <For> at all.

Comment: As a quick followup: I was able to conduct what I wanted to do using a <Vec<Vec<i32>> Signal with the input having an on:input call of the signal and an effect that updates the signal row/column change. A NodeRef would still be more efficient since i'm not manipulating the data and only reading it. Providing the working workaround tomorrow.